# Karma angular unittest runner fails for no apparent reason

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Karma angular unittest runner fails for no apparent reason, doesn't  run any test and just shows (in the cli):

> Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux) ERROR    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
> <     at /home/Documents/Projects/angular/app/index.html:2 Chrome
> 30.0.1599 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.314 secs / 0 secs)

but the index.html file is just standard .. at it runs perfectly with the app. and the "offending line" is just:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

The browser shows only the default:

Karma v0.10.2 - connected
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux) is idle

most of the files are just from angular-seed. And I verified that even If I comment everything in my controllerSpec.js to the original state I get the same error message:

this is the karma.config (annotated for things I tried):

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
    basePath : '../',

    files : [
        'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'app/lib/angular/angular-resource.js',
        'test/lib/**/*.js',
        'test/lib/angular/**/*.js',

//        'app/lib/bootstrap-gh-pages/assets/rainbow.js',
        'app/lib/jquery/jquery.js',
//        'app/lib/**/*.js',
        'app/js/**/*.js',

        'test/unit/**/*.js',
        'app/index.html'
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'], //fails with Firefox also


    plugins : [
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-coverage'
            ],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    },

        reporters:['coverage','dots'], //also tried 'progress' removing 'coverage' and removing the while reporters block. nothing helped


        preprocessors : {
        '**/js/*.js': 'coverage'
    },

//      

})}
```

this is run-test.sh:

## !/bin/bash

BASE_DIR=`dirname $0`

```
echo ""
echo "Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------"

karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/karma.conf.js $*
```

No tests are actually run.
I saw
The e2e running script does work.

Any clues? (running on ubuntu 13)
I'll be glad for help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suite fails because you have included an html file among the files. `<` is an unexpected character javascript-wise. Only javascript files should be in the files list.

Comment: Also json files can be added. as used for fixtures (mock data).